# How to run Javascript in template while all scripts are at the bottom?

Tags: jquery, templates, cakephp, lazy-loading, deferred-loading

I use CakePHP and in the template I pushed every script-tag down right before the closing body tag to get a fast pageload. Now in the body, before the script-tags, there is some code which relies on jQuery (slider and charts). So I used the document.ready-function for that but nothing happens.
What Do I have to do to achieve a working script?

Some code for you to get an insight:

The template index.php

```
... html stuff ...
... the following line fetches the content which contains jQuery functions ...
<?php echo $this->fetch('content'); ?>
... html stuff ...
<?php 
    echo $this->Html->script('jquery'); 
    echo $this->Html->script('jquery-ui-1.9.1');
    echo $this->Html->script('rhinoslider-1.05'); 
    echo $this->fetch('script');
    echo $scripts_for_layout;
    echo $this->Js->writeBuffer(); // Write cached scripts 
?>
</body>
```

In the fetched content there is for example the slider function:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#slideshow').rhinoslider();
});
```

My approaches:
I tried it too with window.onload which doesn´t work either. Due to my understanding of the document.ready- and onload-functions I absolutely don´t have any further clue why it´s not working. I rely on you guys :) Thanks in advance.

Comment: It looks like you're trying to run your script before the required scripts are actually loaded. What happens if you move `fetch('content')` after you load the scripts?

Comment: do you get any error on console? also have you check if jquery is actually loading?

Comment: thanks guys, the answer below was the point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like this results in you trying to use `$(document).ready()` before `$` is available. You'll need to make sure that jQuery is loaded before you make any call to `$()`. Try loading jQuery in the `<head>`.

Comment: Thanks, that was it :) Dumb error of me :D Is it good practice to use DOMCOntentLoaded instead of $(document).ready then?

Comment: @Karl Easy mistake to make, done it myself several times. `$(document).ready(function() { /* code here */ });` is probably best. As long as you've loaded jQuery it's fine. It's worth reading the jQuery page on [the .ready event](http://api.jquery.com/ready/). Glad to help.